# A big "smallest" number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What is the smallest natural number $N$  such that moving the last digit to the front one gets the number $9N$? In other words, find the least $N$ such that if $N$ has decimal expansion $abc...xyz$, then $9N$ has decimal expansion $zabc...xy$. (Note: the number being asked for is very big!).

**HINT:** For solving this question I have calculated the powers of $10$ modulo $89$ for which I have used just $89k$ with $k = 1, 2, 3,...,9$ (sorry for the bad English).

Another related question inspired from this one has been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1233573/move-the-last-two-digits-in-front-to-multiply-by-6).

Comment: My preliminary calculations indicate that no such number exists. I'll double-check and post as an answer if I can confirm.

Comment: You mean if the decimal expansion of $N$ is $abc\ldots xyz$ then the decimal expansion of $9N$ is $zbc\ldots xya$? With $a\ne0$, this is not possible

Comment: I forget the obvious a = 0, Hagen von Heitzen. On the other hand, there are an infinity of such numbers the smallest of them  being10112359550561797752808988764044943820224719

Comment: Put on hold as off-topic? I built this problem from a similar and much simpler property given by Euler I do not remember where. The answer is not immediate but is not very difficult.

Comment: Sorry I can't arrive to eraser this unvoluntary unnecessary comment: I built this problem from a similar and simpler property given by Euler I do not remember where. The answer is not immediate but is not very difficult.

Comment: @LuisGomezSanchez: OK, so your question got put on hold. Your example tells me, that the OP is misleading. You want $N$ such that when the last digit is put in front we get $9N$. Suppose such a number has $m=k+1$ digits. Then $$9N=\frac{N-9}{10}+9\cdot 10^k\iff N=\frac{9(10^m-1)}{89}$$ and since $10$ has order $44$ modulo $89$, the solutions are the $44s$-digit numbers $$N=\frac{9(10^{44s}-1)}{89}$$ which is a complete solution set.

Comment: The first being $N=\frac{9(10^{44}-1)}{89}=10112359550561797752808988764044943820224719$ and the next being $$\begin{align}N&=\frac{9(10^{88}-1)}{89}\\&=\scriptsize{1011235955056179775280898876404494382022471910112359550561797752808988764044943820224719}\end{align}$$

Comment: Right! and your s of the exponent 44s shows that there are an infinity of such numbers (a question I did not wanted to ask) Besides the a = 0 of a comment above must be discarded by the question itself.

Comment: @LuisGomezSanchez: Yes, having the first digit equal to zero is unconventional and should not be included unless specifically stated to be, I would say.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen - No, the OP means that if $N$ has decimal expansion $abc...xyz$, then $9N$ has decimal expansion $zabc...xy$. (I think this way of putting it is clearer than the wording used so far.)

Comment: @String: Why don't you turn your comment into an answer?

Comment: @user87690: I would if I could, but the question is on hold until potentially one more reopen vote has been cast :o). But thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Clearly, the first digit has to be $1$ and the last has to be $9$. Then we have
$$
9N=\frac{N-9}{10}+10^k\cdot 9
$$
where $N$ has $m=k+1$ digits as a total. Solving for $N$, this leads to
$$
N=\frac{9(10^m-1)}{89}
$$
and since $10$ has order $44$ modulo the prime $89$ we get solutions for $m=44s$, ie.
$$
N=\frac{9(10^{44s}-1)}{89}
$$
which for $s=1$ yields
$$
N=\color{blue}{1011235955056179775280898876404494382022471}\color{red}9
$$
which has
$$
9N=\color{red}9\color{blue}{1011235955056179775280898876404494382022471}
$$
as desired.

Comment: Very beautiful presentation!

Answer (score 8):

*This in an answer to the original formulation of the question, where the performed operation was swapping the first digit with the last digit, rather than moving the last digit to the first place while rotating the number.*

No such $N$ exists. Let $a$ be the first digit of $N$, $b$ the last digit of $N$. We demand that $N + b · 10^n - a · 10^n + a - b = 9N$, where $n + 1$ is the length of $N$. We have $(b - a)(10^n - 1) = 8N$. Since $a, b ∈ \{1, …, 9\}$, we have $b - a = 8$, $b = 9$, $a = 1$ and $N = 10^n - 1$, which is a contradition.

Comment: @Elaqqad: $(10^n - 1)$ is not divisible by $2$.

Comment: You have wrong dear friends user87690,mjqxxx, and user31415; read the comment to Hagen von Heitzen,please.

Comment: @LuisGomezSanchez: The way you were asking seemed to be at best misleading. I made an edit to your question so that it is now consistent with the example of an answer you gave in the comment section to the OP. I also solved it in the comments ... Check if those things are correct.

Comment: I appreciate a lot String.

Comment: @LuisGomezSanchez: Maybe you know how to answer my [related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1233573/move-the-last-two-digits-in-front-to-multiply-by-6) then?

Comment: I did not try to do it but I know the way to arrive to an answer. Maybe this comment will not be published  (before I suggested you that your 10 must be changed by 100 if you want, because neither the 10 nor 100 is necessary and the comment has not appeared)

Answer (score 1):

No such $N$ exists. The first and last digits of $N$ are $1,9$, respectively.

$$9\cdot \overline{1a_1a_2\ldots a_n 9}=\overline{9a_1a_2\ldots a_n 1}\iff 8\cdot \overline{a_1a_2\ldots a_n 0}=-80$$

But $\overline{a_1a_2\ldots a_n 0}>0$, impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a \neq 0$ be the first digit, $x \ge 0$ be the middle portion (with $L$ digits), and $b$ be the last digit.  Then
$$
N = 10^{L+1}a + 10x + b,
$$
and we need to have
$$
10^{L+1}b + 10x + a = 9N = 9\cdot 10^{L+1}a + 90x + 9b,
$$
or
$$
80x = (10^{L+1} - 9)b - (9\cdot 10^{L+1} - 1)a.
$$
Unless $b=9$ and $a=1$, the right-hand side is negative; so we need
$$
80x = (10^{L+1} - 9)\cdot 9 - (9 \cdot 10^{L+1} - 1) = -80,
$$
which is impossible.