# Move the last two digits in front to multiply by $6$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics

Here is the problem:

> Can you determine the smallest natural number $N>0$ not divisible by $10$, such that when you move the last two digits of $N$ to the front, shifting the other digits two places to the right, you end up with $6N$?

For example $N=1234567$ will not work, since $6N=7407402$ whereas moving the last two digits in front results in $6712345$. It is not allowed to fill in zeros in case that helps, so $67012345$ is not an option in the current example. Also note, that the last two digits must remain **in the same order** as they originally were. Also you can only use base 10 numbers.

The current question was inspired by [this other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1233056/a-big-smallest-number#comment2508369_1233056) found on this site.

Comment: Last 2 digits moved to the front in the same order as previously or in any order?

Comment: @David: Good question! Same order. I'll update.

Comment: I know the question, dear friend String (if you had asked not for moving two digits as you did but for just one then the corresponding smallest number would have 58 digits while mine was 44). I am waiting for the number of digits in your question).

Comment: I believed your "not divisible by 10" is not necessary to put; however if you want to put it then you have to take 100 instead of 10.

Comment: Base 10 only or any integer base?

Comment: @David: Base 10 only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we take $N=100b+a$ with $10^{n-1} < b < 10^n$, then the specified condition is:

$$\begin{align}\\ 
a10^n+b &=6(100b+a) \\
(10^n-6)a &=599b\\
\end{align}$$

So $599$ is prime and therefore we need $599 \mid (10^n-6)$, that is, $10^n \equiv 6 \bmod 599$. This happens first for $n=297$. To bring $a$ into range, and avoid multiples of $10$, we need to multiple by $61$. In principle, then, we will need $N = \dfrac{6100(10^{297}-6)}{599}+61$

[Check the digits out here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=6100*%2810%5E297-6%29%2F599%2B61)

---

I solved the reverse problem first, by mistake. In this version, I shift the first two digits of $N$ to the end, and that gives six times $N$.

$$\begin{align}\\ 
6(a10^n+b) &=100b+a \\
(6\cdot 10^n-1)a &=94b\\
\end{align}$$

We cannot have $b=(6\cdot 10^n-1)$ so we must have $94 \mid (6\cdot 10^n-1) \implies 47 \mid (6\cdot 10^n-1)$

So the smallest value for which this is feasible is $n=44$, where:
$(6\cdot 10^n-1)/47 = 12765957446808510638297872340425531914893617$

In order for $a$ to have two digits, we need $b$ to be $5$ times this number (giving $a=10$), and

$$N=1063829787234042553191489361702127659574468085$$

Comment: OK, this looks great! A slightly altered approach yields $$N=\frac{61(10^{299}-1)}{599}$$ which gives the exact same result.

Comment: Yes, it's probably just my split into $a$ and $b$ bleeding through into the final formula there.

Comment: And the reverse problem was fun too :o).

Comment: My choice of equation was $$6N=\frac{N-x}{100}+10^k x$$ which can be rewritten to the form $$N=\frac{x(10^m-1)}{599}$$ and the rest follows ...

Comment: I got a slightly better solution... I will just use that same number as the person that got the checkmark and just use a smaller font than he did and that will be a better answer cuz it is smaller (physically smaller like on paper).  Ha ha it is a joke, no downvotes please.

Comment: @David: Just a technical issue here: how do I downvote a comment :P

Comment: @Joffan: Then why not $$\tiny{}_{{}_{10183639398998330550918196994991652754590984974958263772954924874791318864774624373956594323873121869782971619365609348914858096828046744574290484140233722871452420701168614357262103505843071786310517529215358931552587646076794657762938230383973288814691151919866444073455759599332220367278797996661}}$$

Comment: I don't think there is a way to downvote a comment but someone could just  find a previous question the "bad" commenter posted and downvote that for spite.

Answer (score 1):

First thing to note: your $N$ and $6N$ have the same number of digits.

Since we're working in base 10, this means we know that our number is less than or equal to $16…6$ and greater than $10…0$, since if we multiple $9…9$ (one less digit than the numbers before) by $6$, we'll get one digit more than $9…9$ has.

That's a fairly small window, and also, it gives us the first digit of $N$ as $1$. This narrows down our search for the first digit of $6N$ also: it can be no less than $6$. Thus, the 5th digit of $N$ can be no less than $6$.

Now, let's say $N = 100b + a$ for $60 < a < 100$ and $1000 < b < 1666$.

Then we also know $6N = 10000a + b$. Then we have that $9999a - 99b$ is divisble by 5, so $101a - b$ is divisible by $5$, thus $a - b$ is divisible by $5$. This tells us that the 6th digit of $N$ is either exactly the 4th digit of $N$ or their difference is $5$.

Comment: I seem to have assumed there are 6 digits and I don't know why.

Comment: Your observation that $N$ and $6N$ must have the same number of digits is correct as well as your considerations about ranges for the first digits - as far as I can see. Assuming the total number of digits to be six is very limited, though :)

Comment: Where I say "5th digit of $N$", I'd have been right to say 2nd to last digit of $N$.

My derivation that the $a$ and $b$ parts share the last digit or have it differ by 5 is valid for any $N$. Observe that if $999…9a - 99b$ is divisible by 5, then so is $9a - 9b$, thus so is $a-b$.

Everything I said on the 6-digit case does indeed apply for any number of digits.

Answer (score 1):

Let $N$ have $m+1$ digits. We have $N= 100x+10a+b$, where $x$ has $m-1$ digits. Moving the last two digits in front we obtain,
$$6N = 10^ma + 10^{m-1}b + x \implies 600x + 60a + 6b = 10^ma + 10^{m-1}b + x$$
Hence, we need
$$599x = (10^m-60)a + (10^{m-1}-6)b = (10^{m-1}-6)(10a+b)$$
This means $599$ divides $(10^{m-1}-6)(10a+b)$. Further, $10a+b$ is a two digit number and $599$ is a prime. Hence, we need $m$ such that $599$ divides $10^{m-1}-6$. This gives us $m=298,597,\ldots$. I trust you can finish it off from here.

Comment: Great job! You would have reached the same result without specifying individual digits, namely $N=100x+y$ and $599x=(10^{m-1}-6)y$ where $y$ is a two-digit number. BTW: If you don't mind me asking, what should this $y$ be to match the criteria?